# how to memorize and randomize the questions in MCQ?

Tags: vb.net

Dears,

I'm looking for assistance in visual basic with respect to multiple choices questions (MCQ).

by using visual basic for Visual Studio 2015

apply the codes without using database:

1- how to Not make any duplications in the questions?(for memorizing purpose... what is wrong and what is right?) E.g. Assuming I open the program and the first question is the word “rich” ,and I chose the correct answer, which is “IT”, I don’t want to see “rich” again until I finish with the whole list. However, if I make the wrong choice for “rich” for anything else e.g. “HR”, I want the word “rich” to appear after a while until I get the question correct. The point here to make the person memorize “rich” is “IT”.

Please write the codes down in your comment (the point you answering)

sorry for asking long question

Thank you

```
Public Class Form1

Private Structure questionsNanswers
    Public Q As String
    Public A As String
    Public QT As Integer
    Public QC As Integer
End Structure

Private wstart As Integer = 0
Private adad As Integer = 10
Private QA(9999) As questionsNanswers


Private word(15) As String

Private aray(15) As Integer



Private Sub RandomizeArray(a As Integer, ByRef array() As Integer)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim tmp As Integer

    Randomize()
    For i = 0 To a - 1
        j = Int((6 - i + 1) * Rnd() + i)

        tmp = array(i)
        array(i) = array(j)
        array(j) = tmp

    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' next

    CheckEntry()

    wstart = wstart + 1
    If wstart >= adad Then
        wstart = 0
    End If

    WriteText()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ' previous

    CheckEntry()

    wstart = wstart - 1
    If wstart < 0 Then
        wstart = adad - 1
    End If

    WriteText()
End Sub

Private Sub CheckEntry()

    RadioButton1.Visible = True
    RadioButton2.Visible = True
    RadioButton3.Visible = True
    RadioButton4.Visible = True

    RadioButton1.ForeColor = Color.Black
    RadioButton2.ForeColor = Color.Black
    RadioButton3.ForeColor = Color.Black
    RadioButton4.ForeColor = Color.Black

    RadioButton1.Checked = False
    RadioButton2.Checked = False
    RadioButton3.Checked = False
    RadioButton4.Checked = False

End Sub


Private Sub WriteText()

    Dim out As Boolean = False

    For kk = 0 To 6
        aray(kk) = kk
    Next
    RandomizeArray(7, aray)

    Do Until out
        For j = 0 To 3
            If out = False Then
                If aray(j) = QA(wstart).QT Then
                    out = True
                    Exit Do
                End If
            End If
        Next

        For kkk = 0 To 6
            aray(kkk) = kkk
        Next
        RandomizeArray(7, aray)
    Loop

    RadioButton1.Text = word(aray(0))
    RadioButton2.Text = word(aray(1))
    RadioButton3.Text = word(aray(2))
    RadioButton4.Text = word(aray(3))

    Label1.Text = CStr(wstart + 1) & ") " & QA(wstart).Q
    ' ==============================
    Dim go As Boolean = False
    If go Then
        Dim msg As String
        For ll = 0 To 6
            msg = msg + CStr(aray(ll)) + "|"
        Next

        MsgBox(msg)
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    word(0) = "TA"
    word(1) = "GR"
    word(2) = "HR"
    word(3) = "FIN"
    word(4) = "commercial"
    word(5) = "Proc"
    word(6) = "IT"

    QA(0).Q = "rich"
    QA(0).A = word(6)
    QA(0).QT = 6
    QA(0).QC = -1

    QA(1).Q = "Tal"
    QA(1).A = word(1)
    QA(1).QT = 1
    QA(1).QC = -1

    QA(2).Q = "sau"
    QA(2).A = word(2)
    QA(2).QT = 2
    QA(2).QC = -1

    QA(3).Q = "pat"
    QA(3).A = word(3)
    QA(3).QT = 3
    QA(3).QC = -1

    QA(4).Q = "del"
    QA(4).A = word(5)
    QA(4).QT = 5
    QA(4).QC = -1



    WriteText()

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Identical code, same issues, same abbreviations and same verbiage as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47701041/1070452)

Comment: You code looks really big for some one to read through. You need to be specific and point which line is having the issue. What is the desired behavior?

Comment: i delete the previous post...rearranged it (just like you told me plutonix)....now, is there possibility (plutonix or anyone please) to assist me solving my question problem above?.... really appreciated.

Comment: thank you sunil....for the first point i dont know how to combine the structure in this codes (random array part ) Private Sub RandomizeArray(a As Integer, ByRef array() As Integer)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim tmp As Integer

    Randomize()
    For i = 0 To a - 1
        j = Int((6 - i + 1) * Rnd() + i)

        tmp = array(i)
        array(i) = array(j)
        array(j) = tmp

    Next......that what i think the problem for the first point

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421973/reading-to-a-file-line-by-line-multiple-choice-quiz-vb-net/47426722#47426722)

Comment: thank you zack ... but i want it without using data base like i mentioned in the question

Comment: i really appreaciate and thankful for you zack... however, there is no other way to avoid using database?

Comment: is there a away how to do it without using database please ?...thanks

Answer (score 1):

Procedures :

1•Store the questions in a database(E.g. MySql/MSSQL/EXCEL)

2•In the database, create a table of 6 columns(column 1 for questions,column 2 for mcq option1,column 3 for mcq option 2, column 4 for mcq option 3,column 5 for mcq option 4 and finally column 6 for mcq answer )

3•Add 1 label and 4 Radio buttons

Now all you have to do is follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421973/reading-to-a-file-line-by-line-multiple-choice-quiz-vb-net/47426722#47426722) and use the code..

That'll do the work

Comment: i really appreaciate and thankful for you zack... however, there is no other way to avoid using database?... and does that solve my second  point in the question ( memorizing thing)?

Comment: yeah, it'll do the 2nd thing to

Comment: anywa, using the database is the best option , there are other options but they are more complex

Comment: offcourse im really thankful for you zack and really appreciate your kindness  and time....but still i want a solution for my issue without database....(since my knowledge about using database is very weak) and im not looking for copy codes and paste.....like my codes i understand how it work so i just need to understand what should i add to it and what are the codes missing to make it work 100%.

Comment: zack can i ask your assistance please? i want to apply your answer but im stuck at the beginning ...(the options coloumns 1,2,3,4 should i put any answers in them randomly or i just leave them empty?).... second i try to connect visual basic with data base but its seems there is an issue with (connectionstring.open) always red line under it i cant fix the issue... not sure how to connect it... please help...thank you